# How do I get an interactive Bash subshell with exactly the same current environment as the parent shell?

Tags: bash

I would like to create a script for myself—and many other users—that will configure the environment for using a specific version a tool set… and then open an interactive shell using that environment.

What seems to be happening is that the various users initialization scripts (`~/.bashrc`) are executed and breaks a portion of the setup.

Many of the users (including myself) have a default version of the tools configured in their `~/.bashrc`… and want to keep it that way.

The alternate version that I am making this script for is only used a small portion of the time.

I have tried the following:

```
setup the environment
bash
      # runs ~/.bashrc and breaks the setup

bash -i
      # runs ~/.bashrc and breaks the setup

bash --rcfile <(echo echo in subshell... $PATH)
      the displayed $PATH is correct - but I immediately return
      to the parent (no longer a subshell - not interactive)

bash --rcfile -i <echo echo in subshell... $PATH)
      the displayed $PATH is correct - but I immediately return
      to the parent (not a subshell)
```

We don’t want to . `source` the file I can already do that: We want to be able to `exit` back to the previous environment.

So… Hw do I get an interactive Bash subshell with exactly the same current environment as the parent shell?

For what it is worth, I would like this to work on both RedHat and Ubuntu environments.

Comment: Not 100% sure of what you are attempting to do, but have you looked into [`tmux`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) and possibly [`screen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bash --norc -i
```

> `--norc`
>   Don’t read the `~/.bashrc` initialization file in an interactive shell. […]

There's a similar option (yet you don't need it for non-login shells):

> `--noprofile`
>   Don’t load the system-wide startup file `/etc/profile` or any of the personal initialization files `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile` when Bash is invoked as a login shell.

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash))</sup>

If invoking `bash` is the last thing your script does, you may `exec` to it:

```
exec bash --norc -i
```